# Ubuntu 18 hotspot only lasts a few seconds

Tags: networking, wireless

My problem is whenever i make my laptop a hotspot, using Ubuntu 18.04 and connect my phone to the hotspot it only lasts a few seconds. My phone cant connect to the hotspot again unless i turn it off then on on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
 description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
       logical name: wlp13s0
       version: 00
       serial: a8:a7:95:6e:46:53
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.15.0-20-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEE
```

Comment: Watch the system log messages! In a terminal window, type `journalctl --follow`, then "make my laptop a hotspot".

Comment: Check your firewall and ensure you have enable the forwarding. What soft do you use to turn your computer into an hostspot ?